# Log4j2 programmatic configuration Log filename issue

Tags: log4j, java-8, simpledateformat, log4j2

I have configured Log4j2 using programmatic configuration.Please find my code below.I am running this code on jdk1.8.The log files are getting generated properly but log file names are not created appropriately as the pattern defined.The file would get generate with names like `test_28_12_2016_24.log`
Looks like SimpleDateFormat is not getting recognized.Please let me know if i am missing anything.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        public final String LOG_FILE_PATTERN = "-%d{dd-MM-yyyy-HH}.%i.log";
        public final String MY_LOG_PATTERN_LAYOUT = "%msg%n";   

        /* Configuring Logger context */
        private LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
        final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(MY_LOG_PATTERN_LAYOUT, null, config, null,null,true, true, null, null);


        /* Configuring policies */
        final TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy timeBasedTriggeringPolicy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), "true");
        final SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(1024*1024*10);
        final CompositeTriggeringPolicy policy = CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(timeBasedTriggeringPolicy,sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy);
        final DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("50", "1", null,null, null, false, config);

        /* Creating appenders */
        final Appender appender = RollingFileAppender.createAppender("target/logs/test.log" , LOG_FILE_PATTERN, "true", "log-file-appender", null, null, "true", policy, strategy, layout, null, null, null, null, config);
        appender.start();
        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};

        /*Creating loggers*/
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("true", Level.ERROR, "FILE_LOGGER", "com.*", refs, null, config, null);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender,null,null);
        config.addLogger("logger" , loggerConfig);
        context.updateLoggers();
    }

    public void writelogs() {
        Logger logger = context.getLogger("logger");
        logger.error("test data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file pattern should include the file name for multiple logs in the same directory, but i believe the issue is with not having the correct directory in the filepattern. It is probably creating or failing to create the files in another directory.

The file pattern should be something like this.

```
"target/logs/test-%d{dd-MM-yyyy-HH}.%i.log"
```

Comment: Also which version of log4j2 are you using? I know for at least 2.3 the createPolicy() methods accept a string as an argument. ie '10MB' for size and '1' for time

Comment: At the very least I do not think this will produce the desired output and could also cause your files not to rollover as expected. `final TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy timeBasedTriggeringPolicy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), "true");`